# How to specify Runtime dependency in .gemspec file?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I created a gem(apple_store_search). It depends on two other gems(curl and json). My .gemspec look like

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
require "apple_store_search/version"

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = "apple_store_search"
  s.version     = AppleStoreSearch::VERSION
  s.authors     = "Shamith c"
  s.email       = "shamithc@gmail.com"
  s.homepage    = ""
  s.summary     = %q{This is for searching in app in apple store}
  s.description = %q{Exited to watch its progress}

  s.rubyforge_project = "apple_store_search"

  s.files         = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
  s.test_files    = `git ls-files -- {test,spec,features}/*`.split("\n")
  s.executables   = `git ls-files -- bin/*`.split("\n").map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
  s.require_paths = ["lib"]

  # specify any dependencies here; for example:
  #s.add_development_dependency "rspec"
  s.add_dependency('curl', '0.0.9')
  s.add_dependency('json', '1.7.3')
  s.add_runtime_dependency('curl', '0.0.9')
  s.add_runtime_dependency('json', '1.7.3')
end
```

I build this gem successfully. Then I am trying to load this gem on irb, I got error that

```
NameError: uninitialized constant AppleStoreSearch::Search::CURL
```

This error is due to curl gem.

if I require 'curl' and 'json', my gem executed correctly.

How to load these gems(json and curl) by default while loading 'apple_store_search' gem ?

Comment: Although this question is rather old, I want to mention, that `add_dependency` is an alias for `add_runtime_dependency`. See [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Specification.html#method-i-add_dependency) at ruby-doc.org.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference top level namespace in your code ::CURL instead of CURL